# Need helped understanding .resx variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, resx

I am working on a project for my company, and while tracing previously written code I came upon this:

```
<value>A payment authorization for {0:C} has been received.</value>
```

What does {0:C} mean?  I have been trying to find out and am having no luck.

Comment: It is a string format specifier.

Comment: Any idea what it is specifying, or is that defined somewhere else in the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a string like any other string. Once loaded into memory, it will be used as the format parameter to `string.Format`. `{0:C}` just means to format the number as currency using the current UI culture (or is it just current culture? I can never remember).

Comment: Put another way, it's simply a string, but `String.Format()` searches the string for these patterns and replaces them with another formatted string.

Comment: Thanks.  That should help get me started.

Answer (score 3):

It's [formatting a number as currency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8s7t687%28VS.71%29.aspx).